# Turning 4 metric coordinates of Vector into a Vector field

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have four 3*3 matrices:

```
X1=[[2.276840271621883, 2.329662596474333, 2.3633290819729527], [2.276840271621883, 2.329662596474333, 2.3633290819729527], [2.276840271621883, 2.329662596474333, 2.3633290819729527]]
X2=[[2.2698145746531786, 2.3308266405107805, 2.3594316100497643], [2.2698145746531786, 2.3308266405107805, 2.3594316100497643], [2.2698145746531786, 2.3308266405107805, 2.3594316100497643]]
Y1=[[48.832151066337865, 48.84935494957576, 48.86990145209316], [48.832151066337865, 48.84935494957576, 48.86990145209316], [48.832151066337865, 48.84935494957576, 48.86990145209316]]
Y2=[[48.83251302946139, 48.85024866127781, 48.86928223168673], [48.83251302946139, 48.85024866127781, 48.86928223168673], [48.83251302946139, 48.85024866127781, 48.86928223168673]]
```

I would like to create a vector field containing 9 vectors going from

```
(X1[i][j],Y1[i][j]) to (X2[i][j],Y2[i][j])
these are coordinates
```

I have tried using quiver, but I have a dimension problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output? At the moment, I find the problem unclearly formulated. PS When you give an example, try not to use floats. Give examples with symbolic variables or simple integers.

Comment: I would like to have a 2D graph with the vectors in it (the vectors having their coordinates defined as stated in the post): i going from 1 to 3 and j going from 1 to 3: for example a quiver style vector field.

Comment: Alright, understood you now. Please be aware that the matrices you've provided are of rank 1, because the rows in each matrix are identical,  so you'll only get to see 3 arrows if you plot them using the answer I've provided, even though 9 are drawn (they overlap).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to plot a set of arrows using matplotlib's `quiver` function, that start at points `Pi = (X1i, Y1i)` and "end" at points `Qi = (X2i, Y2i)`, you call `quiver` like this:

```
# creating demo data
X1, X2, Y1, Y2 = [ np.random.random_integers(0, 9, (2,2)) for _ in range(4) ] 
plt.quiver(X1, Y1, (X2 - X1), (Y2 - Y1), angles='xy', scale=1, scale_units='xy')
```

Notice the added arguments in the call to `quiver`. These ensure that the arrows start and end in the provided data coordinates.
The shape for `X1` and the other 3 variables defined here is `(2, 2)`, which was done only to illustrate that `quiver` can work with 2-D arrays. You could make the shape `(3, 3)` to suit your example.

For visualisation purposes and to make the point more clear, I've added some markers to the start and end coordinates:

```
plt.plot(X1.ravel(), Y1.ravel(), 'ro ')
plt.plot(X2.ravel(), Y2.ravel(), 'bx ')
```

which results in this figure:

[image: quiver arrows from begin to end coordinates]

Comment: The issue is that when I use list for X1,X2,Y1,Y2 it says:unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list' . How do I transform the lists/matrix to make them quiver-friendly?

Comment: @ElliottOhayon convert your lists to numpy arrays, which allow you to do the elementwise subtraction that is used in the call to quiver shown here (subtracting a list from a list results in the error you describe, not so with numpy arrays though).